# How to turn off auto-login

Tags: gui, settings

Help!!!

I have set up a separate account up on my pi for my brother, but my Pi signs in at startup instead of asking for username and password.

> **How can I switch off the auto login and prompt for credentials on each boot?**

All answers will be appreciated!

Comment: What distro are you using?  It *shouldn't* be logging in automatically as pi unless you've done something really strange.

Comment: you should buy your brother his own SD card, this offers the ultimate data protection and security.

Comment: @goldilocks Doesn't Raspbian have an option for auto-login to desktop in `raspi-config`? I thought it did, has that changed recently and I missed it? Like user1231's answer below. Shouldn't the `Boot-Behaviour` option control auto-login?

Answer (score 5):

Call up the Terminal, type `sudo raspi-config` select `boot-behaviour` and choose Command Line.

When the Pi starts up, it will show a load of diagnostic reports and then a prompt for a username and password. To then get to the desktop, type `startx`

Answer (score 2):

<strike>The login depends on configuration, I got mine from Maplin (UK) and it is set to auto-login with the 'pi' account and launch the GUI by default, so I would assume that it has been configured like that by the retailer you've got it from (As I saw a lot of questions/articles/etc. about how could one login to the raspberry pi and similar)</strike>

One thing that comes in to my mind is reversing [this](http://elinux.org/RPi_Debian_Auto_Login) it is for Raspbian, but I think it should work on other distros as well (although not tested)

If you specify the OS distro you are running, I will update with specific instructions

As to explain the process of the reversing the tutorial, just:

> 1. `sudo nano /etc/inittab`
> 2. `#1:2345:respawn:/sbin/getty 115200 tty1`
> 3. Remove the hash
> 4. If a line like: `1:2345:respawn:/bin/login -f pi tty1 </dev/tty1 >/dev/tty1 2>&1` is presented, I would recommend you to comment it out.

***Edit:***
Based on your feedback in the comments, I googled a bit and found this method (as well I have not tested it):

> 1. sudo nano /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
> 2. Find the line `autologin-user=pi`
> 3. Comment it out and then reboot or power off and on again(**CAUTION** Do not unplug and plug the RPi, you could damage it.)

This is the last thing I have found, let me know if it worked.

Comment: I am running Raspbian and I got it as an xmas pressy so I don't know where it was bought.

Comment: I have done as you said would work, but it hasn't worked, it is still logging on as 'pi' and I need answers ASAP now because I have something on my account that my brother CANNOT see.

Comment: @Someone sorry I didn't reply earlier, but yesterday I was not able to check up with the site

Answer (score 0):

This solution works brilliant in Pi4 B model

```
    sudo nano /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
    Find the line autologin-user=pi
    Comment it out and then reboot or power off and on again(CAUTION Do not unplug and plug the RPi, you could damage it.)
```